# Что добавить в jQuery код, чтобы меню закрывалось при клике по части экрана вне меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```js
$('.menu-btn').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).toggleClass('menu-btn-active');
 $('.links-menu').toggleClass('links-menu-active');
});
```

```css
.main-header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn {
 z-index: 100;
 position: fixed;
 top: 15px;
 right: 30px; 
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #FB7DA4;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FBA9A2, #FB7DA4);
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span,
.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::before,
.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::after {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 16px;
 height: 2px;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::before,
.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::after {
 content: '';
 transition: .3s;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::before {
 transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::after {
 transform: translateY(5px);
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn-active span {
 background: none;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn-active span::before {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn-active span::after {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .links-menu {
 z-index: 50;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: fixed;
 top: -100%;
 transition: .5s;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 75vh;
 background-color: #fff;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0 #DCE9F5;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .links-menu-active {
 top: 0;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .links-menu .nav-point {
 padding: 21px;
 font-weight: 700; 
 font-size: 1.6rem;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #455F87;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .links-menu .nav-point:hover {
 color: #FB7DA4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-header">

  <div class="hamburger-menu">
   
   <a href="#" class="menu-btn">
    <span></span>
   </a>

   <nav class="links-menu">
    <a href="" class="nav-point">About</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-point">Services</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-point">Calculator</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-point">News</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-point">Contact</a>
   </nav>
 
   <div class="overlay-burger"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый раз при клике на весь документ, проверить: Если кликнули по меню, прервать функцию (`return`). Иначе - закрыть меню.

```js
$('.menu-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('menu-btn-active');
  $('.links-menu').toggleClass('links-menu-active');
});

$(document).on('click', function(e){
  if( $(e.target).closest('.hamburger-menu').length ) { return; }  
  $('.menu-btn').removeClass('menu-btn-active')
  $('.links-menu').removeClass('links-menu-active');
});
```

```css
.main-header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #FB7DA4;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FBA9A2, #FB7DA4);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span,
.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::before,
.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 16px;
  height: 2px;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::before,
.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::after {
  content: '';
  transition: .3s;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::before {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn span::after {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn-active span {
  background: none;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn-active span::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .menu-btn-active span::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .links-menu {
  z-index: 50;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  transition: .5s;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0 #DCE9F5;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .links-menu-active {
  top: 0;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .links-menu .nav-point {
  padding: 21px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #455F87;
}

.main-header .hamburger-menu .links-menu .nav-point:hover {
  color: #FB7DA4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-header">

  <div class="hamburger-menu">

    <a href="#" class="menu-btn">
      <span></span>
    </a>

    <nav class="links-menu">
      <a href="" class="nav-point">About</a>
      <a href="" class="nav-point">Services</a>
      <a href="" class="nav-point">Calculator</a>
      <a href="" class="nav-point">News</a>
      <a href="" class="nav-point">Contact</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="overlay-burger"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

P.s. в идеале можно бы $('.menu-btn') и подобные вынести за пределы функции, в виде отдельных переменных. Чтобы каждый раз при клике заново не собирались все элементы с этим классом, а сразу доставались из сохраненного списка.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, если честно, я пока знаю только HTML/CSS, а гамбургер меню нужно для проектов, поэтому делаю по урокам, как могу. Не подскажешь, каким образом вынести то, что ты написал за пределы  функции в виде отдельных переменных?

И еще что думаешь о таком варианте js кода:

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.menu-btn')) { 
    $('.links-menu').removeClass('links-menu-active'); // remove active class from the nav
    $('.menu-btn').removeClass('menu-btn-active'); // remove active class from button
  }
}

Comment: @RaulC.  проблема JS.onclick в том, что он может хранить в себе только одну функцию) Т.е. если позже захочется добавить в коде еще один onclick на window - новый будет работать, а этот перестанет. Поэтому, вообще говоря, пишут `window.addEventListener('click', function(){ ... });` А `event.target` указывает на элемент, на который кликнули. Но может получится так, что кликнули по внутреннему элементу меню - а у него нет такого класса, меню закроется. Поэтому надо проверять наличие класса и среди его родителей. Т.е. сводится к коду в ответе - с `closest` )

Comment: @RaulC. А про "вынести" - имелось в виду это → https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/7ryo8ne5/ , хоть это и не так важно)

Comment: спасибо большое